# What does "record rains" mean in a headline?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A newspaper headline said

> Record rains submerge Chennai, kill 29

The headline was written in the *Times of India* newspaper on 17th November 2015. Can anyone explain this noun phrase as used in journalism?

Comment: Have you looked up what *record* (as an adjective/attributive noun) and *rains* might mean? Please edit your question to add that research, along with what is still unclear.

Comment: (Keep in mind that the definition of *record* as an adjective may be significantly different from the definition for verb or noun.  And keep in mind that Google doesn't automatically show you all the definitions -- you need to select one of the dictionaries that a Google search for "define record" gives you.)

Comment: I read this in A Newspaper. In my journalism class, I was told "Record" is A noun used as an adjective to mean 'heavy' and 'hard' or 'higher', I was given many examples like; record temperature= higher temperature, record rains= heavy rain. So the sentence above is simple enough to say, heavy rains submerge chennai, kill 29. I think my teacher S k bharti is all right.

Answer (score 1):

"[Record](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/record)" in the headline is used as a modifier to mean:

> ***the best or most outstanding amount, rate, height, etc, ever attained,*** as in some field of sport   ⇒  ■ an Olympic record,   ⇒ 
>   ■ a world record,   ⇒  ■ to break the record for the long jump
>
> (as modifier)   ⇒  ■ a record time

[Collins Online Dictionary]

"*Record rains*" means "the heaviest rains ever recorded in Chennai". But you can never know if it is the *actual record* unless there are some specific modifiers, i.e. "record rains *in 10 years*" means it is the heaviest rains *ever recorded in 10 years* and "record rains in history" means the heaviest rains since the meteorological observation started.

In addition, you never know whether it is the record for two-day-long rains or a-week-long rains unless it is specified.

Your teacher is not wrong to say that it means "heavy" rains. But, "record rains" are much bigger than "heavy rains" in terms of "amount of rains" that poured in Chennai.